# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element clicking span element using Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on a span class located inside a div class. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="modal-content scrollbar">
  <div class="block block-always-show action-black-box waves-effect">
    <div class="icon xray-icon"></div>
    <span class="txt">Xray - Test Product Research</span>
</div>
```

Still learning Selenium but here's what I've tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, txt) and contains(text()='Xray - Test Product Research')]").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Xray - Test Product Research']"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='txt' and contains(.,'Xray - Test Product Research')]"))).click()
```

I am getting these errors:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

and

```
TimeoutException: Message:
```

Thanks in advance and appreciate any help on a solution.

Comment: Could you post the url of your page?

Comment: check if your element is present within the iframe

Comment: Could be a problem with XPath. Can you paste this in console and see if you get any result `$x("//span[contains(@class, txt) and contains(text()='Xray - Test Product Research')]")`  if not try this `$x("//span[@class='txt' and contains(text(),'Xray')]")` Note: as mentioned in the above comment, make sure this elemet is not inside a iframe.

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element with text as **Xray - Test Product Research** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.modal-content.scrollbar span.txt"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal-content scrollbar']//span[@class='txt' and contains(., 'Xray - Test Product Research')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path but it looks like your xpath's just need some slight tweaking.
Here are 2 examples that should find the element in question:

This xpath requires the exact text contained in the `span` tags:

`//span[contains(@class, 'txt') and text() = 'Xray - Test Product Research']`

This next xpath accepts snippets of text between the `span` tags:

`//span[contains(@class, 'txt') and contains(text(), 'Xray')]`

You may still need a small wait/time delay to allow for the elements to load on the page before trying to click on them